A problem occurred configuring project ‘:flutter_inappwebview_android’
Could someone help me with the following error in flutter when trying to build "There was a problem setting up project ':flutter_inappwebview_android'".
I have tried clean flutter, get pub, get upgrade, clear cache, reinstall flutter. and nothing has worked for me. I appreciate your valuable help. I put a screenshot of my IDE android studio log.
enter image description here
I have tried clean flutter, get pub, get upgrade, clear cache, reinstall flutter. and nothing has worked for me.

Don't post screencaps of logs or code. ALWAYS post them as text.


I assume that you are using flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0. Can you please make sure the above requirements are satisfied. Reference

Yes, of course, check the requirements and if they are as required by the guide

Check this github thread https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1946
